# How to retag a question without making it go to the top of the question list?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I want to retag posts that have to do with dv6 laptops by HP with the new dv6 tag. I can do this by searching for "dv6" and going down the list and retagging each question with the dv6 tag. The problem is, this makes all the questions pertaining to dv6 automatically move to the top of the question list on the homepage, which crowds out all other questions. So, is there some way I can retag questions without having them go to the top of the question list? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better way to go about this is instead of just reorganizing them is to take the time to just give the [dv6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dv6) tag love in the process, so instead of just mass tagging them all you can:

- Improve the existing questions and answers and help organize them, are some of them duplicates of the others?
- Is there crosslinking you can do between the questions that help them mutually support each other?
- Are any of the questions canonical enough to keep improving and/or mention in the tag description?
- Is there any official documentation on that laptop that could be linked in existing answers?
- Are there entries in the laptop database that can be linked to help users?
- so basically, if you're gonna edit it, make it count!

If you go through a tag with that mindset you'll find that it takes you longer and is more difficult than just organizing, which won't churn the front page as much but makes a huge difference in the quality of the site.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Moderators can bulk-replace/merge tags without (IIRC) floating them all to the top.

Let me know what the two tags are and I'll gently poke them together.

Comment: It's not two tags, I'm looking to have al questions with "dv6" in the title have the dv6 tag added to them, but I don't want them to float to the top of the lis.

Comment: @William I'm not sure that would be a constructive tag change.

Comment: Well, I would like the tag to be used more so it appears higher in the list of tags when people are asking new questions and tagging them.